# Overwritting or changing package.json "homepage" value

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm currently trying to overwrite or change a value in my package.json from another file. Basically, package.json has a "homepage" value that gets built when I run `npm run build`. I wish to be able to change that value from my ***config.js*** or ***config.production.json*** files. I want my environment values all in the config files so it is easier to modify. However, when I run `npm run build`, it still loads my homepage value from the *package.json*.

package.json

```
{
  "homepage": "/company/portal"
}
```

config.production.json

```
{
  "configPath": "/newCompany/portal"
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean in general how to write a file in the client machine through a script in the browser, it isn't a thing allowed so easily and you will have also a lot of cross browsers issues implementing it by 0.

You could try to take a look to this library which seems quite good:

https://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/

You can also think to start an AJAX request to a node.js application for example which will write you the file easily on your system or provide a download, or in general to server side which will provide a file to be downloaded to the client.

But, from the case you explained, you just need to change the config file in your system, so considering you are using node.js, the easiest way is using node.js

It is usually strongly discouraged to put your env variables values inside a JSON file. It can seem that you keep things in order but most probably your code will be pushed somewhere and so opening the JSON file, anyone can see all your values of the env variables. And this is not a good thing.

In my opinion you should think to write your build script in order to take arguments when called, and then call the build passing the parameters. For example:

```
npm build --production
npm build --development
```

Depending on the parameters, you will set up the right configuration on the fly.

I hope this helps

Comment: Very interesting answer. I'll probably look into it later. For now, my workaround is I give homepage this value **"."** and give a new path in my config file.

Comment: Could you expand on why it isn't safe to place my paths in Json files? Is it better in Js files? And why? Thanks

Comment: Nope sorry, I meant that it's not good in general for env variable values. But specially related to security issues as I explained above. 
But if you want to store just your paths, this doesn't make a problem at all. 
I still suggest you to provide custom build passing parameters, you may need CI/CD and there you can simply trigger the build passing parameters. And you may need also other changes between production and development for example. I hope it helps

Comment: Ok I'll keep that solution in mind. So far, only my network info and paths are in my json file

Comment: Good. Thanks for clarifying that !